# Running terraform apply gives Unauthorized for Kubernetes provider deploying k8s resources in Azure Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, rbac, azure-aks

I'm deploying an `AKS` k8s cluster with terraform.

The cluster has rbac enabled with azure active directory.

The cluster creation goes fine and after that terraform tries to perfom some taks on the cluster like creating `k8s-roles` `storage classes`...., and fails there with an `Unauthorized` error message, like this :

```
module.k8s_cluster.module.infra.kubernetes_storage_class.managed-premium-retain: Creating...
module.k8s_cluster.module.infra.kubernetes_cluster_role.containerlogs: Creating...
module.k8s_cluster.module.infra.kubernetes_namespace.add_pod_identity: Creating...
module.k8s_cluster.module.infra.kubernetes_storage_class.managed-standard-retain: Creating...
module.k8s_cluster.module.infra.kubernetes_storage_class.managed-premium-delete: Creating...
module.k8s_cluster.module.appgw.kubernetes_namespace.agic[0]: Creating...
module.k8s_cluster.module.infra.kubernetes_storage_class.managed-standard-delete: Creating...

Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/infra/k8s-roles.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "containerlogs":
   1: resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "containerlogs" {



Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/infra/k8s-storages-classes.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-standard-retain":
   1: resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-standard-retain" {



Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/infra/k8s-storages-classes.tf line 14, in resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-standard-delete":
  14: resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-standard-delete" {



Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/infra/k8s-storages-classes.tf line 27, in resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-premium-retain":
  27: resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-premium-retain" {



Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/infra/k8s-storages-classes.tf line 40, in resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-premium-delete":
  40: resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "managed-premium-delete" {



Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/infra/r-aad-pod-identity.tf line 5, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "add_pod_identity":
   5: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "add_pod_identity" {



Error: Unauthorized

  on .terraform/modules/k8s_cluster/modules/tools/agic/helm-agic.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "agic":
   1: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "agic" {
```

As you can see these are not `azure` errors, but `kubernetes`

It seems like I don't have rights to perform the above resources creation task on the newly created cluster.
What and where to do in order to grant my user account permissions for these terraform task?

Comment: How did you configure the Terraform Kubernetes provider? Have you statically define TLS certificate credentials or you are using your current kubectl context?

Comment: None of both, I used terraform with my azure account, I don't have any context setup for terrafom actually

Comment: Have you done : az aks get-credential?

Comment: Found this post from kubernet.dev fixed my issue in a sec. it has to do with Azure AKS AAD 
https://www.kubernet.dev/terraform-and-aad-rbac-integration-for-aks/

Comment: @Oren this should be posted as an answer, even if it just copy/pastes from the URL, there's no guarantee people won't get 404 in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is to change your kubernetes provider configuration from

```hcl
provider "kubernetes" {
  load_config_file       = "false"
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.host
  username               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.username
  password               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.password
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

to

```hcl
provider "kubernetes" {
  load_config_file       = "false"
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.host
  username               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.username
  password               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.password
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

If the local accounts are disabled this will not work, but you can use this instead :

```hcl
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.this.kube_config.0.host
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.this.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command = "./kubelogin"
    args = [
      "get-token",
      "--login",
      "spn",
      "--environment",
      "AzurePublicCloud",
      "--tenant-id",
      var.tenant_id,
      "--server-id",
      var.aad_server_id,
      "--client-id",
      var.client_id,
      "--client-secret",
      var.client_secret
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that you'll need to include the [kubelogin](https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin) binary in the repo. More details [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/aad-integrated-kubernetes-cluster-no-longer-able-to-use-kubernetes-provider-following-disabling-local-admin-account/33439).

Comment: Do you know any solutions where the local account is disabled? My company forces me to disable the local account usage.

Comment: @LukasHeiligenbrunner : Can you try the code I've set in my edit ?
I canot test that at the moment